# Table names in front of field names when using SELECT *

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2014

I was wondering if there is a possibility to show full column names when using `SELECT *` in combination with `JOIN`.

As an example I have this query (which selects data that gets imported from another application):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.SomeKey = t2.SomeKey
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.SomeOtherKey = t3.SomeOtherKey
```

This gives me results like this:

```
+---------+------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+
| SomeKey | Name | Value | WhateverId | SomeKey | SomeOtherKey | ValueType | CategoryId | SomeOtherKey | Value | ActualValueId | SomeTypeId |
+---------+------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+
| bla     | bla  | bla   | bla        | bla     | bla          | bla       | bla        | bla          | bla   | bla           | bla        |
+---------+------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+
```

What I'd like to have is the table name in front of each field. The results would be something like this:

```
+----------------+-------------+-------+------------------+
| Table1.SomeKey | Table1.Name | ..... | Table2.ValueType | .....
+----------------+-------------+-------+------------------+
| bla            | bla         | ..... | bla              | .....
+----------------+-------------+-------+------------------+
```

I want to do this because the query is already given (without `SELECT *`) and I now have to find a column in one of the tables with values that match a given identity from an additional table. I know I could analyze each of the tables. However, I'd like to know if there is any simple statement I could add to get the table names in front of the field names.

Comment: Define each field's name explicitly.

Comment: @IvanStarostin That's too much effort. It would even be faster to analyze the tables individually.

Comment: 'That's too much effort' really? Just half ass it for all time then. Either that or do it properly. And also, if I was reviewing production code and saw SELECT * that code would be thrown out on it's ass.

Comment: @RichBenner I'm using the `*` just to find the desired column. In the actual query I'm later specifying the needed columns.

Comment: You could do this if you're struggling to see what table contains what data will give you a column between each table SELECT 'Table1' Table1, t1.* 'Table2' Table2, t2*, 'Table3' Table3, t3.* it

Comment: @RichBenner In my case your idea would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer to that question is **NO** . You can't alias the columns using the `*` .

If you want to work around with the columns, specify them your self and alias them as you'd like, in general I try to avoid the use of `*` to avoid ambiguously columns.

Think about that this way - 2 more minutes of work to avoid a possibilitiy of errors that will take you 100X of it.

Comment: I'm using the `*` just to find the desired column. In the actual query I'm later specifying the needed columns.

Comment: You can't do it later, you'll get `ambiguous column` error if two columns has the same name.

Comment: I'm going to do it with aliases then. I just wanted to know if there is a statement that adds the table names to the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily build yourself the `SELECT` clause using `AS` for each column. Let's say you have the following tables:

```
IF  OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table01') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table01;
END;

IF  OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table02') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table02;
END;

CREATE TABLE Table01
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Age] TINYINT
);

CREATE TABLE Table02
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Age] TINYINT
);
```

and you query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table01
INNER JOIN Table02
    ON Table01.[ID] = Table02.[ID];
```

Just execute the following statement:

```
SELECT ',' + [source_table] + '.' + [source_column] + ' AS [' + [source_table] + '.' + [source_column] + ']'
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set  
(N'SELECT *
FROM Table01
INNER JOIN Table02
    ON Table01.[ID] = Table02.[ID]', null,1) ;
```

You will get this:

[image]

Just copy and paste the result to your query (and remove the first comma):

```
SELECT Table01.ID AS [Table01.ID]
,Table01.Name AS [Table01.Name]
,Table01.Age AS [Table01.Age]
,Table02.ID AS [Table02.ID]
,Table02.Name AS [Table02.Name]
,Table02.Age AS [Table02.Age]
FROM Table01
INNER JOIN Table02
    ON Table01.[ID] = Table02.[ID];
```

and you will get this:

[image]

Of course you can play with the output of the [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) and build the `SELECT` columns in a way you like (excluding columns, formatting it, etc).